# How can I set up collection select correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, view

With the code below, if I hit Search it takes me to these url

```
With FireFox > http://example.com/shop?utf8=%E2%9C%93&genre[]=1
With Safari  > http://example.com/shop?utf8=✓&genre%5B%5D=1
```

How can I remove this "[]" and "%5B%5D"?
Only I want is "&genre=1"

**View code**

```
<%= form_tag communities_path, :method => :get, :class => 'form-search' do %>
   <div class="input-append">
    <%= collection_select :genre, nil, Genre.all, :id, :name %>
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Search</button>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= select_tag :genre, options_for_select(Genre.all.map{ |g| [g.name, g.id] }) %>
```